# webform_submission_insert $submission values

Tags: 7, webforms

I am writing a module where I need to grab the submission values of a [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)

I am using the webform_submission_insert hook found [here](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_component_insert/7) however when I print out the $submission array using this:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($submission).'</pre>', 'warning');
```

All I get is this:

```
<pre>1</pre>
```

It appears to me this hook is not working correctly and is not populating the array. How can I get the submission values?

I am using Webform version 7.x-4.0-alpha6. The webform I created has about 10 different input fields.

Comment: I am also getting the same results when I downgrade to 7.x-3.18 and use webform conditional 7.x-1.0-beta1.

Comment: spare yourself ache and pain and install the devel module. use dpm(), kpr() etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was printing the array out incorrectly. Using this code to print works:

```
drupal_set_message(''. print_r($submission, TRUE) .'');
```